# How does serialization work, and What can not be serialized?

Tags: python, ruby, serialization

Sometimes we serialize objects when programming as we can use it under other scenario or save it persistently.

However, I'm wondering:

1. How does serialization work? We write down all instance variables as a string, write down its class, and then **initialize** it according to its class, assigns instance variables back to it, right?
2. What kind of **things** can be serialized and what kind of **things** can not? If not, why not? Can you give some specific examples (maybe in ruby or in python etc.)?

Thanks.

**Update:**

As for *2.*, my colleague told me that things like I/O, Proc (in ruby), singleton class can not be serialized. To be more specific, things can not be determined statically. However, I don't really understand what does **determine statically** means. So, can you elaborate it a little bit more?
Thanks.

Comment: It all depends on what serialization method you're using.  If you're using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), for example, it defaults to serializing the instance's `__dict__`.  As for #2, see [What can be pickled and unpickled?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that ["When a pickled class instance is unpickled, its `__init__()` method is normally *not* invoked."](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getinitargs__)

Comment: Side note: I guess in theory, you can serialize any object. If you define the serialization to be some kind of memory dump including class definitions and so on, you could serialize any object. Of course there are limitations in practice. For example you could certainly serialize an object representing a network connection, but it would probably not be very useful.

Comment: @jedwards Thanks. I'm aware of pickle, but I'm a little bit more interested in ruby's `to_yaml` in fact. But I guess the principles are similar, right?
@p11y I updated a little bit context. Could you help explain more? In a "answer" form would be more appreciated :-) Thanks.

Comment: @lazywei, I can't speak to ruby specifically, but yes I'd imagine the concepts are the same.  As for your latest edit, (and again, I can't speak to ruby), I see no reason why singleton classes couldn't be serialized -- at least in general.  But I see why serializing Proc objects would be difficult.